# How can I retrieve the image from a vcard photo SHA-1 Hash with XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

I have below the case where I am getting an SHA1 HASH of an image. Now how can I convert it to an `Image`.

For your information, this is XMPP code where I am getting User Information as below and photo in SHA1 HASH format.

```
<presence from='juliet@capulet.com/balcony'>
    <x xmlns='vcard-temp:x:update'>
        <photo>sha1-hash-of-image</photo> 
    </x>
</presence>
```

I am a beginner to C#, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should ask yourself "What is a hash?" And do research to answer that question. RSA Labs: [What is a hash function?](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2176) Wikipedia: [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Comment: Thanks Jonathon for you advise.. i will check this link..

Comment: Long story short, the original message **can not** be recovered from just a hash.  A hash is fixed-length, no matter how big the input. Think about it, would you expect to be able to recover a full 4GB movie from just a 20-character string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. A [SHA-1 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is effectively just a fingerprint of an image - it doesn't contain the image itself.

Given [this extension document](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html) it looks like the idea is that the vCard contains the *actual* data - and the vCard update just contains the hash, so that clients which have already fetched (and cached) this image before can check that their cached version is still valid, fetching the full data if not.

From [section 3.2](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html#retrieve):

> When the recipient's client receives the hash of the avatar image, it SHOULD check the hash to determine if it already has a cached copy of that avatar image. If not, it retrieves the sender's full vCard in accordance with the protocol flow described in XEP-0054 (note that this request is sent to the user's bare JID, not full JID)

Comment: thanks for you reply but documents say so that is image but any other way to convert it to string ..may be it is image url..

Comment: @SwetaTiwari: No, it's really not. See the link in my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a user's VCard, you should load the VCard for that user using their jid (or extended jid... i don't know what C# xmpp library need to load a VCard).

But, once the VCard is loaded, you should be able to get the raw value for the photo within XML. The value for photo will be a base64 encoded string, so you should base64 decode the string into a binary byte string or byte array, again dunno what C# XMPP lib offers, as far as extracting avatar data.

After you do that, you can either convert it into an image. In java, this is done like:

```
VCard vcard = new VCard(xmppConnection);
try {
    vcard.load("someone@xmpp-server-somewhere.com");
} catch (XMPPException e) {}
byte[] avatar = vcard.getAvatar();
```

BTW: The SHA1 hash is to just compare to see if the image has changed from last time :)

Hope that helps~~